# Conditional value for ActiveRecord create method only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a form where I have an administrator creating new users.  The form uses the User model I created (login, password, first_name, etc...).  For the last field on the form, I want to have a checkbox that doesn't need to be stored as part of the User record, but it is needed for the controller.  This will control if the newly created user will receive a welcome email or not.  This is in Rails 3.0.3.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    if @user.send_welcome_email
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    end
    redirect_to(admin_users_url, :notice => "User #{@user.name} was successfully created.")
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

In my view (haml) I am trying to access it like this:

```
  %p
    Send Welcome Email?
    = f.check_box :send_welcome_email
```

I tried to make this an `attr_accessible: :send_welcome_email`  but the controller does not recognize it.  I get an

```
undefined method 'send_welcome_email' for #<User:0x00000100d080a8>;
```

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

What is the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not `attr_accessible`, but `attr_accessor`. That's it.

However, your code will look nicer if you move the email sending code to an observer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not saving it on the user, you can use check_box_tag instead of f.check_box and access it with params[:send_welcome_email]. Although even the way you have it, I think you could access it as params[:user][:send_welcome_email].

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `attr_accessor`, you can always remove it from the parameters first:

```
def create
  send_welcome_email = params[:user].delete(:send_welcome_email)
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver if send_welcome_email
    redirect_to(admin_users_url, :notice => "User #{@user.name} was successfully created.")
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

You may have to make sure that the parameter is successfully transformed into a boolean; otherwise the condition will always be true (`0` is `true` in Ruby).